# Solving $a_n = a_{n-1} + 7n$ for $n\ge1$ and $a_0 = 4$

Tags: recurrence-relations

First, I found the homogeneous solution:
$$r^n - r^{n-1} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow r = 1$$
So the homogeneous solution is of the form: $$c(1)^n = c$$
Then, to find a particular solution, I "guessed" the form $An+B$, then plug it into the equation:
$$An+B = A(n-1)+B+7n$$$$\Rightarrow A = 7n$$
So I assumed the solution would be $c + 7n^2$, then plugging in $a_0 = 4$ gives c =4, so the final solution (incorrect) is $$4 + 7n^2$$

But after comparing with some values, the **solution is obviously wrong**.

I recently started learning how to solve these linear recurrence relations, and it's really confusing, so hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The way you manipulated $A$ does not depend on $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be the right-shift operator:

> $R = ( f \mapsto ( n \mapsto f(n+1) ) )$.

Then your equation is:

> $(R-1)(a) = ( n \mapsto 7n )$.

Apply $(R-1)$ to both sides repeatedly until the right-hand side vanishes!

> $(R-1)^2 (R-1)(a) = ( n \mapsto 0 )$.

Now we can use the general solution for homogenous linear recurrence relations:

> $a = ( n \mapsto (pn^2+qn+r) 1^n )$ for some $p,q,r$.

Note that if the right-hand side had a term of the form $n^k c^n$, apply $(D-c)$ to both sides repeatedly and it will vanish.

As for why your attempt is invalid, it is because you made a logical error; if you guess that $a_n = An+B$ for some **constant** $A,B$, and you get $A = 7n$, which is not a constant, it implies that your guess is wrong. If you guessed $a_n$ is a quadratic in $n$, you would be able to solve for the coefficients. Why you need a quadratic in general is explained completely by the above solution.

Comment: Thank you for the superb explanation, especially the last paragraph! I finally get it now!

Comment: @TonyTarng: You're very welcome! For more on this see the links in my profile. =)

Answer (score 4):

That method doesn't apply to this type of recurrence.

For this one, it's probably simplest to work out the first few terms and guess the pattern.

\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 4\\
a_1 &= 4+7\cdot 1\\
a_2 &= 4+7\cdot 1+7\cdot 2\\
a_3 &= 4+7\cdot 1+7\cdot 2 + 7\cdot 3\\
\ldots
\end{align*}

So $a_n = 4+7(1+2+\cdots+n) = 4+7n(n+1)/2$

Comment: Could you elaborate why this method doesn't apply here?

Comment: As I learned it the method using roots of polynomials only applies to linear homogeneous recurrences.  I.e. $x_{n+1} = a_0 x_n+a_1 x_{n-1}+\cdots+a_m x_{n-m}$.  Since the term $7n$ is there, this one doesn't fit.  There may be generalizations I don't know about though.

Comment: Don't be too quick to assert that a method doesn't work! See my answer for how to use it properly. =)

Answer (score 4):

If the generating function is allowed, then this can be solved as follows:
Define $$\color{blue}{f(x):=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n}.$$
Then from the recurrence relation, we have:
$$a_nx^n=a_{n-1}x^n+7nx^n.$$
Summing over $n,$ we have $f(x)-a_0=xf(x)+7\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nx^n.$ Since $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=x\dfrac{d(1/(1-x))}{dx}=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2},$$ we conclude that $$\color{red}{f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)}(4+\frac{7x}{(1-x)^2})}.$$
Expanding it out, either by differentiating twice the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$ or by binomial theorem applied to $(1-x)^{-3},$ we obtain :
$$a_n=4+\frac{7n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the $(1-x)^{-3}$ in this answer corresponds to the $(D-1)^3$ in my answer, due to correspondence between $(D-1)(a)$ and $(x-1)f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on this correspondence! :D

Comment: You're welcome. I prefer to use $R$ whenever possible, but generating functions can do many interesting things that cannot be expressed using $R$. And it's nice that one can put in the initial conditions straightaway in the generating function. Sorry my earlier comment should have said "$R$" not "$D$" lol..

Comment: To a so lazy man as me that the various methods out there for recurrence relations in existence are too complicated, using the generating functions at the first place seems to be a good habit: it can lead to solutions even if one does not know how to guess. :P

Comment: Well some things are very elegantly done with operators and not with generating functions (see the links in my profile under "Forward Difference Operator"), so I guess it's best to know both. =)

Comment: Yes, I always admire the beauty of such operators as $R$ and the coefficient operator, or those of the same kind. :D

Answer (score 3):

Given
$$ a_{n}-a_{n-1} = 7n $$
it follows that:
$$ a_N-a_0=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(a_{n}-a_{n-1})=\sum_{n=1}^{N}7n = 7\cdot\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
so:
$$ a_N = \color{red}{4+\frac{7N(N+1)}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your form for the particular solution is wrong, because it contains the solution of the homogeneous equation ($B$).  Try $An + B n^2$.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more? How can you tell $An + B$ won't work?

Comment: @TonyTarng: See my answer for why your reasoning is incorrect and how one can know to try a quadratic. It also explains Robert's remark in the following sense: Since the original homogenous part of the recurrence is $(R-1)(a) = 0$, we know that when we have a polynomial in the non-homogenous part, we need to apply $(R-1)$ to both sides repeatedly to vanish it, and recall that if you have $(R-c)^k$ in the characteristic part then the corresponding term in the general solution is $P(n) c^n$ where $P$ has degree $k-1$. So both homogenous and non-homogenous parts contribute to the characteristic.